# PhoneGap / Cordova clone

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I got one version of an app running with Cordova which my friend would like to get a copy of but instead of copying the whole "www" folder and then reinstall plugins etc in a new project is there a way to simply clone the project including plugins etc? So that we only would have to change the package name? com.package.my

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out than for capacitor, cordova / phonegap you can just change the config.xml details  and the packagename afterwards reinstall platforms.